# github pull request ignore status checks after pushing commits

Tags: git, github, jenkins, pull-request

I have a protected brach in github with require status check - Jenkins build.

When a user is creating a pull request, The Jenkins test is starting and that's ok. But when a user is pushhing commit to the branch of the pull request - the test is starting again, even if the user didn't finish to work on this branch, and he has some more commit to send - and he didn't want to check the current code because it is not ready.

I there a way to configure the branch protection that the status checks will be called just when the user finished to work on this PR?
Something like the *update branch* button:
[image]

(My Jenkins build is very heavy and long and I want it to be called just when necessary.)
[image]

Comment: What would be the definition of "the status checks will be called just when the user finished to work"

Comment: The user will need to click on a button - just like the current github option for out-of-date code:  "This branch is out-of-date with the latest branch" and the user needs to press the "update branch" button

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Create the PR when the work is ready and not before.
2. Work with the 2 protected branches workflow, e.g. `develop`->`main` (or `main`->`release`/`live`/etc.) where you first put features into `develop` and only when desired you merge them into `main` which has the Jenkins task attached.
3. You could not run the check automatically on push then teach users to trigger them with a commit message. 
   From
   [Skipping and requesting checks for individual commits](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/collaborating-on-repositories-with-code-quality-features/about-status-checks#skipping-and-requesting-checks-for-individual-commits):

   > When a repository is not set to automatically request checks for pushes, you can request checks for an individual commit you push.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > To request checks for a commit, type your commit message and a short, meaningful description of your changes. After your commit description, before the closing quotation, add two empty lines followed by request-checks: true:
   >
   > ```
   > $ git commit -m "Refactor usability tests
   > >
   > >
   > request-checks: true"
   > ```

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  My problem is that usually the Jenkins test finds issues in the users' code and then they need to fix the code after the Jenkins test.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it on every PR open or reopen and then on synchronize do a check of the commit message for some keyword. The only asterisk for this solution is that it would require the dev to be informed in the commit message keyword. Could also force it to fail if the keyword isn't present so that merging is blocked.